# Uploading data to create a table for use in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am currently working on developing reports on SSRS. This specific report was initially built on excel using a query that is quite comple. I noticed it pulls about 2 million records  and thus slow due to several joins and subqueries. I was trying to create a table instead dedicated to have this data readily but i got an error (query taking too long ) and timed out while trying to execute it as a SELECT * INTO ReportTable From. Please any assistance is well appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Increasing the connection timeout  would be a cheap work a round.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chuck. Will try that

Comment: You should try and improve the underlying query if possible and then you can store it in a temporary table to use in the report. Perhaps you can post the underlying query and ask for help in improving it?

Comment: Look into `Bulk Insert`. It's much faster at loading tables like this.

Comment: @Anand Thanks. Will send a copy of the query

Answer (score 0):

You can either run this directly on the DB host, or you can create an SQL Server Agent job that performs this. It should prevent the time out.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew O'Brien